# generating sql script of query performed using c# code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, generate-scripts

Hi I am working on a project,where I am generating sql query for CRUD operations performed on a table having xml data in one of its column.I have successfully generated sql queries and for now I am displaying those query in a textarea and saving those query in a .txt file but now I want that those query could be saved to a .sql file. For now I am storing my query in a text file with the below code.

Query for update

```
sqlQuery = "update tblCCBT_Step_Page_Text_Xml set Xml_XmlData.modify('replace value of (/page/*[position()="+xmlNodeIndex+"]/text())[1] with " + newValue + " ') where Xml_Id = " + xmlId;
            string a = Server.MapPath("~/Content/dbScripts");
            string dt = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            dt = dt.Replace(":", "-");
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(a + "\\editNode_"+dt+".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            writer.Write(sqlQuery);
            writer.Close();
```

I want my query to be saved in .sql file.Please suggest how to proceed further.Thanks

Comment: The text that you are storing in the text file, is that the full query that you want to store in a .sql file?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `+".sql"` instead of `+".txt"` ? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: yes I want to save my query in .sql file rather than text file

Comment: Use FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(a + "\\editNode_"+dt+`".sql"`, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write); instead of FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(a + "\\editNode_"+dt+".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

Answer (score 1):

A .sql file is the same as a .txt file, just with a different extension.  This is testable by putting a New Document on your desktop, name it query.txt, put SQL (something simple like `SELECT 'A'`) in it, save, and rename it to query.sql.

You should be able to just replace the ".txt" with ".sql".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save my query to a .sql file by just replacing .txt to .sql.

Updated code

```
sqlQuery = "update tblCCBT_Step_Page_Text_Xml set Xml_XmlData.modify('replace value of (/page/*[position()="+xmlNodeIndex+"]/text())[1] with " + newValue + " ') where Xml_Id = " + xmlId;
            string a = Server.MapPath("~/Content/dbScripts");
            string dt = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            dt = dt.Replace(":", "-");
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(a + "\\editNode_"+dt+".sql", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            writer.Write(sqlQuery);
            writer.Close();
```